# Angular 8+ Fire event in App.component.ts AFTER child view inits

Tags: angular, hubspot

I am trying to add HubSpot page tracking to my Angular 8+ app. Currently, I am hooking into the NavigationEnd event on my router within `app.component.ts`. The problem I am having, is the page title gets set in each child component, so the HubSpot code runs before the title is set, and the analytics are wrong. Is there a way to hook into "after child loaded" globally from the app.component.ts? I realize I can add data attributes to my routes with the titles there , that only works for static titles. Many of my components fetch data, then display the title afterwards.

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'app';
  constructor(private router: Router, private titleService: Title, public settings: SettingsProvider, private navService: NavigationService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    let win = <any>window;
    var _hsq = (win._hsq = win._hsq || []);

    this.router.events.subscribe((evt) => {
      if (!(evt instanceof NavigationEnd)) {
        return;
      }

      if (_hsq != undefined) {
        console.log('tracking hubspot page view');
        _hsq.push(['setPath', evt.url]);
        _hsq.push(['trackPageView']);
      }
    });
  }
 }
```

Comment: Did you try Resolver?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try Resolver?

```
{path: 'path/:id', component: YComponent, resolve: { yourData: YourResolver}}
```

Comment: It seems you forgot to put a link to the mentioned description.

Comment: I have over 300 components. This would be a HUGE lift to implement. Is there any other way?

Comment: So can you change your tracking view to listen api calls that changes page title?  Or mabye use MutationObserver for title change?